# Java program to trace file copying

Tags: java, file-copying

I want to write a java program which will run in background and trace which file is copying from which source to destination. This program will write this info to a log file. But I am not sure from where to start. Is there anyone out there who can help me to find the starting point?

### Edit

I have no restriction to use java. I am open to use any programming language even if its any kind of shell script, I am totally ok. (but only thing is I am on win7). But java would be better :)

Comment: What's doing the file copying?

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually I have a big collection of ebooks, videos and audio files. Sometimes I arrange them in my external hdd and I later forget where I put them. I just want to write a small helper for me, which will show me later which file I copied where. So, its me who will do the file copying.

Comment: You need a CMS, or use something built in to the OS (e.g., spotlight/etc under OS X), or only move them around under an app you control, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Read this to see how to organize file system watches
http://e-blog-java.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-watch-file-system-for-changes-in.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can know both the source and destination of the copy (at least in Java), but in Java 7 there is a way to watch a directory for `create/modification/delete`.  Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) tutorial.